# I can't find Google Play Billing Library in the Android Studio SDK Manager

Tags: play-billing-library

I'd like to make an android application with in app purchases.
So I read some document and knew that I have to download the Google Play Billing Library from SDK Manager.
But I can't find that library in my Android Studio SDK Manager.
I tried to add `compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'`  to the dependencies section of the build.gradle file for my app.
But I can't still find the library..

[image]

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I got the same question like you. Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to add it to your build.gradle dependencies, have a look at [these docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html).  So it won't appear in the SDK manager.  Once you've added the dependency in build.gradle, you'll need to create a billing library client, as per the code in the example in the docs.

Or, have a look at the [billing example provided by Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing).

Comment: Thank you so much. but I can't still do that... Actually i don't understand... I tried to create billing class like those docs.. but it was error, because i don't have the library. And I don't have extra folder in my sdk manager(sdk tools tab) so I can't download the library.

Answer (score 0):

here:https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2993

Solved by re-order repositories from

```
repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}
```

To

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
  jcenter()
}
```